# Replacing a crankset, do I also need to replace the bottom bracket?

Tags: shimano, crankset, bottom-bracket, replacement

I'm planning on replacing a Shimano FC-510 crankset with an FC-R7000. The bottom bracket has had light use (~2000km) and has no obvious play in it, however the videos I've seen showing removal of these types of cranksets suggest I might need to use a soft mallet to get the axle out. Could the crankset removal process damage the BB bearings, and should I have a replacement BB on hand?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the process of removing the drive side crank and axle by tapping with a soft-faced mallet will not harm the balls or races in the bearings. The balls and races are hardened and the axle is not a true 'interference' fit in the inner races so you don't have to tap the axle very hard to get it to move.

You can review the [Park Tool Repair Help page on two-piece crank removal](https://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/crank-removal-and-installation-two-piece-compression-slotted). If there was a danger of damaging the bearings it would be mentioned and steps to avoid it described.

I will note that I have encountered a FSA PF30 crank that was *really* tight in a SRAM BB, but you should not have that problem with Shimano cranks in high quality BB bearings.

Comment: I can verify the tight fit.  I thought I'd done something wrong when I did just this pairing.  I ended up using a block of wood with a mallet and lots of time and patience.  It rolls perfectly well, just a tight fit.

Comment: @Andrew, I had the same problem with FSA bearings so very likely the FSA crank is at fault

Comment: Do you mean that you currently have an FC-5100 crankset which needs to come out? FC-510 (properly, FC-M510) intimates an older Deore MTB crankset that uses either square taper BB's (early versions of the 510) or Octalink BB's in later versions. I suspect a typo.  Hollowtech2 cranksets do require a bit of persuasion after the bearings have been preloaded and a little more so after being ridden in my experience.

Comment: @Jeff I think op has R5** ‘non series’ crank, those are HT 3 piece but are heavy, you get em in bikes where manufacturer is cutting costs